# How to make a for loop iterate through each item in a string with an if statement?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that takes in a string from a user and then outputs the same string. However for each letter in an even position it outputs the corresponding lower case letter, and for each letter in an odd position it outputs the corresponding uppercase letter. Keep in mind only one word will be passed through it at a time.

I've tried to create a for loop with an if statement nested within it, but so far, the for loop stops after iterating through the first letter. My code is below:

```
def converter(string):
    for letters in string:
        if len(letters) % 2 == 0:
            return letters.lower()
        elif len(letters)% 2 != 0:
            return letters.upper()
```

When I run the code:
converter('app')

The output I get is 'A'
The expected output should be 'aPp'

Comment: `len()` is always going to return 1 because the value of variable `letters` is always a single character.

Comment: Your code uses `len(letters)` which is a constant 1 and does not reflect the position of the letter in the string. And you also return upon first letter from the method, you loop never completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that in Python, strings are immutable. So "modifying" a string means you have to build a new string from scratch in (here, I call that `newstring`).

Second, you are misunderstanding the loop. You are saying `for letters in string`. This loop iterates over each letter of the string. On the first iteration, `letters` is the first letter of the strong. You then convert it to upper case (since the length of a single letter is always 1), and return it. You aren't reaching the rest of the letters! In the code below, I change the plurality to just `letter` to make this idea clear.

This amends all of those problems:

```
def converter(string):
    newstring = ""
    for i, letter in enumerate(string):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            newstring += letter.lower()
        elif i % 2 != 0:
            newstring += letter.upper()
    return newstring
```

This can be boiled down to a nice list comprehension:

```
def converter(string):
    return "".join([letter.lower() if i % 2 == 0 else letter.upper()
                    for i, letter in enumerate(string)])
```

Comment: for something with % i would be tempted to code `(letter.lower,letter.upper)[i%2]()` inside that comprehension.  but, of course, we would not expect newbies to understand what that is doing.

Comment: I'm confused. You said strings are immutable, yet you're editing "newstring", even in after the first character is added, it becomes a string...I was wondering if maybe you could clarify

Comment: @VedBrahmbhatt It's misleading syntax, I agree. Each time `newstring += ...` is called, a new string is created from the existing `newstring` and the case-modified `letter`. That new string then _overwrites_ the existing string. The letter is not simply appended.

Comment: @VedBrahmbhatt To convince yourself of this, you might `print(hex(id(newstring)))` at the end of each iteration of the loop. This shows the memory address of the object. Sometimes, the memory address is reused, but if you append enough new letters, you will almost certainly see it change one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: def converter(string):
   ...:     return ''.join([j.upper() if i % 2 == 1 else j.lower() for i, j in enumerate(string)])


In [2]: converter('apple')
Out[2]: 'aPpLe'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join([s.lower() if c % 2 == 0 else s.upper() for c, s in enumerate('apple')])
# returns 'aPpLe'
```

first check for the condition, then iterate through the string using the nice old `enumerate` built-in.